# Mathematical logic in model based diagnosis

Tags: logic, machine-learning, satisfiability

maybe one or the other here is familiar with model-based diagnostics, or perhaps with mathematical logic.

I have a question that probably refers more to the logic behind it. I'll start to explain the problem. Given is a Inverter, if the input of the inverter is 0, then the output is 1 and vice versa. This is always the case if and only if the inverter works correctly.

Now there is a system description called SD, some components COMPs and once the case that the inverter is faulty and once, the case where the inverter
works properly, and some observations OBS

---

**Here are a few definitions:**

$Ab(c)$: component c is ABnormal

$\lnot Ab(c)$: component c is not abnormal, i.e. normal

Inverter: $X$

---

**A drawing of the inverter:**

[image]

---

For example, a (presumed) system description of the inverter might look like this:
$$SD = \{\{A \land \lnot Ab(X) \rightarrow \lnot C\}, \{\lnot A \land \lnot Ab(X) \rightarrow C\}\}$$
Then there is, for example, the Observations OBS abbreviated:
$$OBS = \{A=1,C=1\}$$
That would mean with the input 1 resulted the 1, at the first sight considered something seems not to function properly in the circuit.

I'm trying to understand exactly this:
$$SD \cup \{A=1,C=1\}\cup\{\lnot Ab(X)\}\models\bot \quad\quad Eq.1$$
and this:
$$SD \cup \{A=1,C=1\}\cup\{Ab(X)\}\not\models\bot \quad\quad Eq.2$$

I would just demonstrate what I am thinking at the moment about Equation Eq.2:
I do not know if that's right:
$$\{\{A \land \lnot Ab(X) \rightarrow \lnot C\}, \{\lnot A \land \lnot Ab(X) \rightarrow C\}\} \cup \{A=1,C=1\}\cup\{Ab(X)\}\not\models\bot $$
I transform the logical implications once:
$$\{\{\lnot A \lor Ab(X) \lor \lnot C\}, \{A \lor \lnot Ab(X) \lor C\}\} \cup \{A=1,C=1\}\cup\{Ab(X)\}\not\models\bot $$
To judge by equation Eq.2 this would have to mean: Assumption X is abnormal is consistent. If I understand Eq.2 correctly.
Then Eq.1 would have to mean: assumption X is normal is inconsistent, right?

My question is, how exactly do you do this set-up $SD \cup ... \cup$? How could you get from:
$$\{\{A \land \lnot Ab(X) \rightarrow \lnot C\}, \{\lnot A \land \lnot Ab(X) \rightarrow C\}\} \cup \{A=1,C=1\}\cup\{Ab(X)\}$$
to conclude the consistency / inconsistency, what should be done?

I hope it's reasonably clear what I mean. Thank you for coming answers!